# Haskell - How can I divide a matrix (2-D array) into groups

Tags: haskell, matrix

I have a 2-D Matrix below:

```
mat = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
```

I want to translate it to 4 groups:

```
output = [[1,2,5,6],[3,4,7,8],[9,10,13,14],[11,12,15,16]]
```

In other (imperative) programming languages like Java or Python, I can easily create 4 new lists and iterate from the top left position `(i,j)` of each sub matrix to add the elements in. But in Haskell, I have no ideas how to achieve what I want because it does not support for loop and the recursive loop `(x:xs)` seems not help this case.

[image]

Comment: Your `output` does not seem to consist of matrices. The picture illustrating what you want does.

Comment: Are you limited to 4x4 matrices?

Comment: @gspr: Sorry for the confusion, I want the elements of the sub matrices.

Comment: @TeWu: Thanks for your attention,  No, the sub matrices could be 3x3,4x4 depends on the size of the original matrix [4x4] -> 4 x [2x2], [9x9] -> 9 x [3x3] etc

Comment: @TeWu In the case I'm solving right now, 3x3 matrices are good enough. But if we can find a general solution, that would be great.

Comment: I meant 3x3 sub matrices, not the original 3x3 matrix

Comment: For a general solution, is the input always 4x4, 9x9, 16x16, 25x25, ... i.e the dimensions are n^2 x n^2 of some integer n?

Comment: @4castle Yes, n^2 x n^2

Comment: Thanks @LouisTran - that was a lovely puzzle 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are limited to 4x4 matrices, you can use `!!` ("Get the Nth element out of a list"):

```hs
mat = [
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [ 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [ 9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16]
  ]

output = [
    [e 0 0,  e 0 1,  e 1 0,  e 1 1],
    [e 0 2,  e 0 3,  e 1 2,  e 1 3],
    [e 2 0,  e 2 1,  e 3 0,  e 3 1],
    [e 2 2,  e 2 3,  e 3 2,  e 3 3]
  ]
    where e i j = mat!!i!!j
```

#### General solution

```
filterByIndex :: (Int -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterByIndex p xs = [x | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], p i]

filterByIndex2D :: (Int -> Bool) -> (Int -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
filterByIndex2D pr pc rows = [filterByIndex pc row | (row, i) <- zip rows [0..], pr i]

f :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
f matrix = [
    filterMatrix ( <m) ( <m),
    filterMatrix ( <m) (>=m),
    filterMatrix (>=m) ( <m),
    filterMatrix (>=m) (>=m)
  ]
  where m = (length matrix) `div` 2
        filterMatrix fi fj = concat $ filterByIndex2D fi fj matrix


mat = [
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [ 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [ 9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16]
  ]

output = f mat  -- [[1,2,5,6], [3,4,7,8], [9,10,13,14], [11,12,15,16]]
```

[**Run it**](https://repl.it/@TeWu/dividematrixintogroups)

We assume that `matrix` is a square matrix, and find the index `m` of a middle element. Then we filter the matrix four times based on this index. Note that this probably is less performant than the 4x4 matrix specific solution above.

Answer (score 5):

It's useful to write `chunksOf` which breaks a list into parts, each
of a given size.

```
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf _ [] = []
chunksOf n xs = ys : chunksOf n zs
  where
    (ys, zs) = splitAt n xs
```

For example:

```
> chunksOf 2 "potato"
["po","ta","to"]
```

(If you know about `unfoldr`, you can also write `chunksOf` nicely
using that.)

We can use `chunksOf 2` to get groups of two rows each, `[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]` and `[[9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]]`.

From these we want to group the columns - we can do this by
transposing, grouping rows, then transposing each group back again.

(`transpose` is in Data.List.)

For example, on the first row group, we `transpose` to get

```
[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

Then `chunksOf 2` gives us

```
[[[1, 5], [2, 6]], [[3, 7], [4, 8]]]
```

Then we `map transpose` to get

```
[[[1, 2], [5, 6]], [[3, 4], [7, 8]]]
```

So now we have 2x2 submatrices and the only thing left to get what you
wanted is to flatten each one with `concat`.

Putting it all together:

```
f :: Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
f size = map concat . subMatrices size

subMatrices :: Int -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
subMatrices size = concatMap subsFromRowGroup . rowGroups
  where
    rowGroups = chunksOf size
    subsFromRowGroup = map transpose . chunksOf size . transpose
```

Answer (score 4):

Not very elegant but I think it works.
First we define a function to split the rows in half

```
half xs = (take n xs, drop n xs) 
         where l = length xs `div` 2
               n = if even l then l else l+1
```

So then we merge the list of pairs like so

```
merge []        = []
merge [x]       = fst x : snd x : []
merge (x:y:xss) = (fst x ++ fst y) : (snd x ++ snd y) : merge xss
```

This way we get

```
> merge $ map half [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
[[1,2,5,6],[3,4,7,8],[9,10,13,14],[11,12,15,16]]
```

and

```
> merge $ map half [[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[9,10,11]]
[[1,2,5,6],[3,7],[9,10],[11]]
```

Which seems to be in accord with the picture you provide.